# Apache beam JOIN using java- extensions library (beam-sdks-java-extensions-join-library)

Tags: apache-beam

I am using the below code for join data in the apache beam in java and the beam version is 2.19. (without CoGroupByKey). But I am getting NullPointerException.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong here. Below is the code.

```
public class InnerJoinExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

        Schema left = Schema.builder().addStringField("a1")
                    .addStringField("a2")
                    .build();

            Row row1 = 
                    Row
                      .withSchema(left)
                      .addValues("key1", "5")
                      .build();

            PCollection<Row> leftPCollection = p.apply(Create.of(row1)).setRowSchema(left);



            Schema right = Schema.builder().addStringField("b1")
                    .addStringField("b2")
                    .build();

            Row row2 = 
                    Row
                      .withSchema(right)
                      .addValues("key1", "15")
                      .build();

            PCollection<Row> rightCollection = p.apply(Create.of(row2)).setRowSchema(right);        


            PCollection<Row> joined = leftPCollection.apply(Join.innerJoin(rightCollection));

            p.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. Can you please provide the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Join$FieldsEqual$Impl.access$200(Join.java:89)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Join$Impl.expand(Join.java:203)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Join$Impl.expand(Join.java:156)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:476)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:355)
 at section4.InnerJoinExample.main(InnerJoinExample.java:53)

Comment: this is the exception

Comment: Can you also provide more details about how you are running your pipeline (i.e. which runner and other pipeline options)?

Comment: It is replicable on a direct runner if you import the join class from the Beam SDK `import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Join;`. Is that what you used?  Using `import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join;` gives a type error by the look of it.